# Using Replace Method in a For Loop

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, replace

Despite the code below, the string remains completely unchanged when it is printed out in the `tkinter` grid.  I'd like for it to remove every character in `disallowedCharacters`.  There must be something I'm not understanding about how strings can change.  Note that `itemSeries` is passed to the following code from another function that grabs the text from the web using Selenium.

```
itemSeriesString = str(itemSeries)
disallowedCharacters = "()#1234567890"
for character in disallowedCharacters:
    seriesName = itemSeriesString.replace(character, "")

itemSeriesLabel = Label(frame, text="Series:", font='time 12 bold')
itemSeriesLabel.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='w', padx=10)
itemPrintSeries = Label(frame, text=seriesName)
itemPrintSeries.grid(column=3, row=4, sticky='e')
```

I tried escaping the `(`, `)`, and `#` characters, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: does a "0" get replaced?

Comment: Currently, nothing does, no numbers or symbols.  Not sure if you are asking if it's possible for one to be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remember that `.replace()` never modifies the original string; it returns a new string with the result of the operation.

At every iteration of the `for` loop, you are:

- taking the *original, uncleaned* `itemSeriesString`
- filtering out all instances of one character from that original string
- assigning the result of that filtering to `seriesName`.

You're never accumulating the results of the replacement operations, so most of the forbidden characters will remain.

You should use the same variable on the left and right hand side, so that you can accumulate the results of the replacement operations:

```py
disallowedCharacters = "()#1234567890"
seriesName = itemSeriesString
for character in disallowedCharacters:
    seriesName = seriesName.replace(character, "")
```

Or, even better, just filter out those characters using `filter()`:

```py
seriesName = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in disallowedCharacters, itemSeriesString))
```